# Angular 2 .. Passing an instance or control of form to a service

Tags: angular

HTML for form

Want to call a function recordTemperature which in a tempService file and reset the value from that service.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Temperature Monitor</h1>
    <form [formGroup] = temperatureForm novalidate>

      <div>
        <label for="temperature">Add Temperature:</label>
        <input id="temperature" formControlName="temperature" type="text" required>

      <button (click)="_tempService.recordTemperature(temperatureForm.get('temperature').value);">Add</button>
        <div class="row">
          <div *ngIf="temperatureForm.controls.temperature.dirty && temperatureForm.controls.temperature.errors && temperatureForm.controls.temperature.errors.temp && temperatureForm.controls.temperature.value" class="alert alert-danger col-md-5 col-xs-12">can only contain numeric values</div>  

        </div> 
      </div>
</div>
```

My Component
Importing the TemperatorMonitor from service here

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl,FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms'
import {formValidator} from './formValidation.component'
import {TemperatureMonitor} from './app.temperatureMonitor.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
  providers: [TemperatureMonitor]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  temperatureForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,private _tempService : TemperatureMonitor){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.createForm();
  }
  createForm(){
    this.temperatureForm = this.fb.group({
      temperature : ['',formValidator.temperatureValidator],
    })
  }
```

My Service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class TemperatureMonitor{
     recordTemperature(value){       
      this.temperatureForm.get('temperature').reset();     
    }
}
```

Getting Cannot read property 'get' of undefined error when trying to reset the input data from here.

Comment if need more data or clarification.

Comment: There is no temperatureForm property in your service. It's a property of your component. The service should not deal with form controls. That's not the role of a service. Just do that from the component. Similarly: the template should not access the service of the component. It should call methods of the component, which themselves use the service. BTW, since the service is private, that won't compile in AOT mode. As is, your service doesn't serve any purpose, and should not exist.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, But is there any othe way that I could access the formInsatance in a service

Comment: You **can**, but you **shouldn't**. The role of a service is not to deal with form controls. That's the role of a component. Just like the role of a database access layer is not to display a UI. Why don't you simply put that code in your component?

Comment: @JBNizet Sure.. Thanks